# How to display a contour plot of a parametrical function in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function `g(psi, k)` where `psi` is a two components array and `k` is a real parameter. I would like to display the `g` function in a 3D contour plot with respect to the coordinates `psi` given a selected parameter `k`. How can I do that in Python?

I tried using the function `contour3D` with a wrapper function in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 32 # Change this value to display different plots

# Wrapper of the g function
def f(x, y):
    psi = np.array([x, y])
    return g(psi, k)

x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)
y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='binary')
plt.show()
```

But I get the following error relative to the line `Z = f(X, Y)`:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Running simply:

```
print(f(-0.33, -0.5))
```

I obtain a real value as expected:

```
28.08105396614395
```

How can I fix it? Is there any other way more straightforward to display the plot of `g(psi, 32)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `g(psi, k)` is probably only working with `psi` being a 1D array, meaning only accepting x and y being scalars. Either call `f` in a loop, or vectorize the `g` function. Here is how to call the function `f` in a loop:

```
Z = np.empty(shape=(X.shape))
for row, (xx, yy) in enumerate(zip(X,Y)):          # into rows
    for col, (xxx, yyy) in enumerate(zip(xx,yy)):  # rows to single values
        Z[row, col] = f(xxx, yyy)
```

Comment: Yes I confirm you what you wrote about the `g` function :) your workaround works, thanks! I gave it a +1 but I will wait a little more to confirm it as the correct answer. I hope there is a more compact way of doing this. Thanks again!